# .Net core MVC - submit a form through a controller doesn't return ajax - just the controller's URL with result text

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an index page with a table and a simple form with just two dropdowns. The page also has several divs with partial views on it. On submit, I need it to refresh just those divs and not the whole page.

Someone helped me with the ajax and controller. The form submit works great. It submits the form and does almost everything it should. But on submit, instead of going back to ajax to refresh the divs, it redirects me to the controller's URL with a line that says whatever I pass in the return section. Kind of confusing. I hope the sections below help it make sense.

Form Partial View:

```
<form id="ajax_submit" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CreateBreak" class="DthdropdownGroup ml-3">
<div class="btn-group" style="margin-left:-1rem">
    <select class="form-group dropdownStyling btn-sm dropdown-toggle d-inline-block btn-outline-light" style="width: 7.4em;" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="EmployeeId" asp-for="EmployeeId">
        <option>Dispatcher</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Employees)
        {
            <option class="dropdown-item pr-1 form-control" value="@item.Id">@item.DisplayName</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <select class="form-group dropdownStyling btn-sm dropdown-toggle d-inline-block btn-outline-light" style="width: 7.3em" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="EmpPosition" asp-for="EmpPosition">
        <option>Position</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Positions)
        {
            <option class="dropdown-item pr-1" value="@item.Id">@item.PositionName</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block dropdownStyling" id="break-submit" style="margin-left: -1rem; width:15rem;">Submit</button>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> CreateBreak(int EmployeeId, int EmpPosition)
    {
        Break newBreak = new Break();

        newBreak.EmployeeId = EmployeeId;
        newBreak.EmpPosition = EmpPosition;
        newBreak.TimeEntered = DateTime.Now;

        _context.Add(newBreak);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Json(new { success = true, });
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#ajax_submit", function () {

// prevent regular form submit
e.preventDefault();

var data = {
    EmployeeId: $("#EmployeeId").val(),
    EmpPosition: $("#EmpPosition").val()
}

$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "/Home/CreateBreak",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function () {
        $(" #headerRefresh ").load(window.location.href + " #headerRefresh ");
        $(" .breakRefresh ").load(window.location.href + " .breakRefresh ");
    },
});
```

})

Part of the code from one of the partials to see how I have the partials set up:

```
    <div class="dthRefresh">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Dths)
                {
                    @*////EMPLOYEE SENT////*@
                    @if (item.EmpSent == true)
                    {
                        <tr style="background-color:lightgreen; font-size:large">
                            <td class="w-75 h-25 p-0">
                                <input type="hidden" class="hiddenDthID" value="@item.Id" />
                                <a href="Javascript:;" class="empNameDth" style="color:black">@item.Employee.DisplayName-@item.Employee.DispatchNumber</a>
                            <td class="h-25 p-0" style="font-size:large">@item.EmpPositionNavigation.PositionName</td>
                            <td class="h-25 justify-content-center p-0 pl-1">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

The form submits just fine but when I submit it returns this:

[image]

So instead of refreshing those divs and staying on the index page, it changes the URL to Home/CreateBreak. It should stay on Index and just refresh those divs that are on the index page. I've been stuck for days. I really appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But on submit, instead of going back to ajax to refresh the divs, it redirects me to the controller's URL with a line that says whatever I pass in the return section. Kind of confusing.

That is because you fail to prevent regular form submit.

You miss `e` in `function ()`, change like below:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#ajax_submit", function (e) {

    // prevent regular form submit
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
})
```

Comment: You're right. good catch. Thank you. When I put that in, it stops doing anything at all - doesn't submit.

Comment: Hi, could you pls F12 and check the Console panel in browser what's the error message?

Comment: It looks like I'm getting 500 - "jquery.min.js:2 
 POST https://localhost:44392/Home/CreateBreak 500
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ site.js?v=ot2lAjlOLC…DVO0ZU7cP1DSfuM:120
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2"

Comment: Could you pls check `$("#EmployeeId").val()` and `$("#EmpPosition").val()` value? You can check the value by adding code like: `console.log($("#EmployeeId").val())` before `var data=xxxxx`. And then check the value in Console Panel in browser.

Comment: Also, could you pls check the `Output` panel in visual studio tool if there is any error message?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not seeing a value assigned. It says "Dispatcher site.js?v=mRow04-BNUmcSwjM8YX655Xjn1u-veLGpTrbuSHmF6o:114" but no value. The row below that has the exact same thing for Position. As far as the error  goes, it only has the one above - the 500 message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242975/discussion-between-rena-and-tyler-johnson).